# Smart-Things vs Smartthings

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[smartthings](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartthings) has been created and I get an annoying warning when trying to change it to [smart-things](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-things). Generally all multi-word tags should be hyphenated. Can we please change the tag name.

Since it is a product name / trademark we should likely have one called [samsung-smartthings](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-smartthings) too. We already have one question ([Safety of a smart switch on a fireplace](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/17/smart-switch-on-fireplace)) that is tagged with it without disclosing any Samsung specifics in the question.

Edit: Someone changed it to [samsung-smartthings](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-smartthings).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SmartThings](http://www.smartthings.com/) is a proper noun, not a concept. It's spelled as a single word.

As the brand is getting confused with the concept, I've suggested an edit to change the tag to [samsung-smartthings](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-smartthings).

“Smart things” as a concept is far too vague to be a valid tag.

Comment: In that case let's call it samsung-smartthings to make it clear it's their product name, otherwise people will tag all sorts of stuff with it.