# Essential questions #2: The IoT Tag Taxonomy

Tags: discussion, tags

According to [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta) one of the essential questions is to establish a good base for a taxonomy by using sensible tags.

To help us keep the the taxonomy clean I'll aggregate some in this post and provide a blueprint suggestion for tag wikis in an answer. If this is well received I will expand the list of tags at the bottom of the blueprint over time like I have [over at ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9464/184706).

**How we handle tags so far**

- We use [corporation-productName] tags (cf. [this](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/78)) for physical products of a specific company. Examples are [amazon-echo](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-echo), [samsung-smartthings](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-smartthings), [google-home](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-home) and [philips-hue](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philips-hue). These tags are singular.
- Apparently we use just the service name or protocol for non-physical things. Examples are [mqtt](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mqtt), [alexa](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alexa) and [wifi](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi).
- We prefer [plural tags](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74/should-these-tags-be-plural) whenever we refer to general concepts or generic product categories. Examples are [standards](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/standards), [sensors](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensors), [tracking-devices](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking-devices). Exceptions are words that are uncountable or would change their meaning when pluralized, e.g. [security](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) and [safety](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety).

Answer (score 5):

### Tag Wikis

The structure is a merge from good ideas [over at ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9442/suggested-tag-wiki-blueprint) and has been quite well received. In my opinion the tag wiki should provide answers to four questions:

- What is this tag about?
- Is my question complete?
- What are good example questions?
- I'm wrong here, what other tag do I use?

Those questions are answered by the introductory paragraph and the three lists. In my opinion three defining checks, three examples and three alternative tags should be enough.

### **WYSIWYG Tag Wiki Blueprint Suggestion**

> Use this tag for questions that are about the security of IoT devices (especially those connected directly to the internet) and how to mitigate these issues or avoid them altogether.
>
> The Internet of Things involves objects and entities collectively known as Things. These Things have unique identifiers and the ability to automatically transfer data over a network. As access to Things is over the Internet, security is crucial.
>   Consider the question check list if your question fits the tag. You can also look at the example questions. If this tag doesn't fit your question have a look below at somehow related tags that might fit your question better.
>
> **Question checklist**
>
> - Is the question about the security of IoT devices, setups or networks?
> - Is the question **NOT** about safety? (If it burns it's about safety, if it's hacked then it's security.)
> - Does the question describe clearly what the issue is?
>
> **Example questions**
>
> - [How can I check if my IoT devices are infected with the Mirai worm?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/211)
> - [Can I monitor my network for rogue IoT device activity?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/90)
> - [Intercepting the web traffic from an IOT device](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/18)
>
> **Not what you are looking for?**
>
> - Use [networking](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) for questions about setting up and configuring networks for your IoT devices in general.
> - Use [safety](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) for questions about the operational safety of devices.
> - Consider asking on the [Information Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) if your question has no IoT connection.

---

### Copy-paste blueprint

Copy everything between after the horizontal line, fill out the description, adapt the check list and the example questions and ***pick*** other tags (max 4). Done. Of course, writing more tag specific differentiating tag alternatives is always welcome.

Yeah I know this looks hideous, but no one has to edit this to copy it.

---

`Use this tag for questions that are about INSERT SHORT DESCRIPTION.`

`Consider the question check list if your question fits the tag. You can also look at the example questions. If this tag doesn't fit your question have a look below at somehow related tags that might fit your question better.`

`**Question checklist**`

`- Is the question about the security of IoT devices, setups or networks?
 - Is the question **NOT** about safety? (If it burns it's about safety, if it's hacked then it's security.)
 - Does the question describe clearly what the issue is?`

`**Example questions**`

`- https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/211
 - https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/90
 - https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/18`

`**Not what you are looking for?**`

`- Use [tag:networking] for questions about setting up and configuring networks for your IoT devices in general.
 - Use the product's tag, if it exists, e.g. [tag:amazon-echo].
 - Is your question about **any** publish/subscribe protocol? If so, use [tag:publish-subscriber].
 - For technical problems with a Raspberry Pi, consider asking at [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).
 - Use [tag:protocol] for questions where you don't know or are looking for a protocol.
 - Use [tag:smart-home] for questions about configuring and interfacing smart home devices in general.
 - Use [tag:standards] for questions about the ***content*** of standards.
 - Use [tag:safety] for questions about the operational safety of devices.
 - Consider asking on the [Information Security.SE][1] if your question has no IoT connection.
 - For questions about electronics, consider asking at [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.
 - Use [tag:wireless] for questions about **any** wireless protocol.
 - Use [tag:wifi-halow] for the low power, high range 802.11ah protocol.`

Answer (score 4):

### Tag wiki excerpt

> This tag is for questions about whatever the tag is primarily about. The tag wiki excerpt can at most be 500 characters long. No mark-ups can be used. Only plain text is allowed. Thus, CAPITAL LETTERS are the only way to emphasize in any way. At a maximum one thing should be emphasized with capital letters most likely the primary requirement for questions with the tag. To save space only listing the most commonly mistaken other tag is advised. This example has near five-hundred characters.

*Example: Security*

> For questions relating to the security of IoT devices (especially those connected directly to the internet) and how to mitigate these issues or avoid them altogether. Do not mix up with device SAFETY. (If it gets hacked it's a security question, if it explodes it's a safety question.)

- Stay the hand with the capital letters.
- List the most commonly mistaken tag for distinction.
- Keep it short and simple.
- The beginning phrase This tag is will not be displayed in tag overview page. Continuing the sentence with for questions about will improve the feeling of a more coordinated taxonomy.