# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://iot.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://iot.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: **Please note** that with the anticipated slowdown in traffic during the end-of-year holidays, we will *not* be evaluating this site for public launch until after the new year.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

[image]
[image: profile for Helmar on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because of his strongly active with this site by his avid contributions from the first day of private beta of this site & solved many users questions wisely. First his communication skills that benefits for this site to go further on next levels. If my words still not enough, the reputation is the proof of his passionate towards this site.

[Thanks to him](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339858/adding-link-to-iot-se-private-beta-in-the-iot-tag-on-so) our site's link has been added to the [iot](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iot) tag wiki on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iot/info).

Thanks.

---

I hereby *accept the nominating* because I'm interested in making this StackExchange site successful and bringing it from beta to graduation and onward. I've tried to bring the expertise of being professionally involved in IoT into the beta as well as my personal interest in the matter. Moreover, I've been involved with the IoT proposal since definition and I field the *Precog* badge to prove it.

While I'm usually more of an answering user, I made an extra effort to populate the site with questions, making me one of two users<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup> who has a double digit question count. With those questions I tried to test the scope a bit as well. I consider the emerging *decision about list questions* a win even though my personal score is negative. Now we know a bit better what we do want on the site and what we don't want.

[As Bence already added](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/139/revisions) to this post, I helped spread the word about this site on meta.SO where the people included the site already into the IoT tag info.  That also shows my approach around SE sites. When I am not answering on the main site, I'll always include meta about ideas I have. I am also quite reachable in chat as my UTC+1 location allows.

Since my contribution to this site can only go back two weeks I encourage everyone who is interested to check my main SE site, English. Whoever wants to check out relevant badges or my overall contribution can head over there. My main effort on elu.meta has been around the taxonomy and trying to improve it. Over a few months I have asked over twenty well-received questions on elu.meta, have left a few burninated tags in my wake and [triggered activating a new function on the site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9482)<sup><sup><sub>2</sub></sup></sup>.  It's in part that experience that I used when I gathered up information about [our emerging taxonomy](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/essential-questions-2-the-iot-tag-taxonomy)<sup><sup><sub>2</sub></sup></sup>. While not having massive reputation points on meta.se, I've been reading (and voting) there quite a bit while reading up on the inner workings of StackExchange.

While I like badges (and hats, who doesn't like hats) I do know that ***part of being a moderator is to let the community moderate itself*** and keep the moderator powers in the box and staying the hand in the review queues unless clear cut or really necessary. Especially on the close votes that will keep shaping the scope of the site for some time to come the tricky cases should be decided by the community and not by a unilateral diamond-backed vote.

The important tasks ahead will be to *reinvigorate the site after a loooong private beta* when we hopefully do go public and ***create a climate that makes new and old users feel welcome***, stick around and **want to** ask great questions and provide terrific answers. Having an eye on that would be one the most important tasks as a moderator.

Thus, I hereby throw my fourteen<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup> hats and [four<sup><sup><sub>1</sub></sup></sup> Aurora hats](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34190866#34190866) in the ring.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> At the time of this writing. |</sub> 
<sub><sup>2</sup> My Post</sub>

Comment: I have no doubts that Helmar would make an excellent moderator from what I've seen, so he has my full support. I'm also pretty certain that many other users feel this way, since Helmar has had a massive influence on the site (from the tag wiki blueprint to all his helpful answers!).

Answer (score 15):

[image]

[image]

[image: profile for Aurora0001 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

I'm nominating myself as a candidate for Pro Tempore Moderator in the hope that I can help the site to grow and improve to become a **useful, high-quality** Q&A site for everyone to benefit from.

As a user of this site, I have:

- contributed [lots of questions](https://iot.stackexchange.com/users/12/aurora0001?tab=questions) that I think are interesting and useful to others to help seed the site and set an example of the question quality that we should aim for.
- helped to keep the site clean by editing where necessary (I'm also the first to get the [Strunk & White](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) badge!).
- tried to [share the site](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/105/12) in related communities where possible to help grow the site.

I'm often around in the [Chat of Things](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49682/chat-of-things) room, so feel free to pop along if you want to discuss anything with me. I also (semi-jokingly) developed [AuroraHats](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34190866#34190866), an <strike>unnecessarily complex</strike> interesting alternative to the Winter Bash, since IoT isn't participating, powered by the site's RSS feeds.

In terms of activity, I live in the UK (GMT+0 in Winter, GMT+1 in Summer - see [this page](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london) for DST), and I tend to be around in the afternoon to evening. At weekends I can typically spend more time on the site and I can cover most of the GMT day.

As for my opinions on moderation and community building:

- Stack Exchange's model is fantastic for letting the community determine what's on-topic and high-quality, so I believe in allowing the community to participate in moderation where possible, either through **voting** (e.g. close/reopen votes) or **meta discussion**.
- I feel that we can learn a lot from empirical studies and other model communities to make IoT the best it can be. In particular:

  - Encouraging people to contribute better and better content is a policy I wholeheartedly support, rather than simply downvoting and giving up on users who haven't contributed great content yet. [*How Community Feedback Shapes User Behavior*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1429v1.pdf) is a fantastic study to read on this topic - offering positive, constructive feedback leads to far better outcomes for both the community and the author, so we should aim to do that where possible.
  - Looking to other successful communities such as the [Rust community](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/) is a good plan for helping this site. I've known many users who remark on the community's friendliness, and the root cause seems to be influential leaders who encouraged this behaviour consistently.

If anyone has any questions, feel free to ask below or in chat; I will do my best to respond as soon as I can.

Comment: +1 I've appreciated your focus on keeping the Question/Answer ratios up. It helps to start strong in regards to getting out of Beta. Keep up the good work and good luck!

Answer (score 12):

To break the ice, I'll start with nominating myself, **Ghanima**, as a mod pro tem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

When it comes to IoT I'll have to admit that I am not a professional but an avid enthusiast only (encompassing an interest in Linux, general electronics, and the Raspberry Pi) thus there will always be a subject matter expert more proficient here than me. My main contribution to the site and the team of moderators will therefore not be generating most of the content single-handedly but in community-building and the *janitorial* tasks of keeping the site clean and running smoothly. Besides that I strive for clear and open communication between the moderators and the community - patient and fair, respectful and polite, and as impartial as possible.

I have been an elected community moderator on [RaspberryPi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/19949/ghanima) for a year so far. This has been a great experience and I enjoy the **teamwork of moderators** that is significantly supported by **community moderation** enabled by voting, flags, comments, and editing. Based on the experience with the current users of IoT in our site's chat room I am confident that we will work well together too making this site a success. Key to this is an **open and welcoming community** that embraces new users, guides them to follow the community-defined rules, and turning them into active community members who are eager to come back and share their knowledge. <sup><sub>Learn more about my stance on moderation from the [RaspberryPi's 2015 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/662/19949) - most of which still holds true.</sub></sup>

I am located in UTC+01:00 and visit SE in the morning to check the queues and again in the evening to participate in the main site, meta, and chat.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]
[image: profile for anonymous2 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

#### Notes:

Just throwing my hat in the ring at the recommendation of a user whom I deeply respect.  :)  My nomination as far as my IoT reputation and badges are concerned isn't impressive, mostly because my actual knowledge of IoT is somewhat limited.  However, avid users will bear me witness that I am around loT.SE, especially in chat and review queues.

I do believe that my personality is conducive to the role of moderator, and would willingly put in the work that it would take to help out as a pro-tem moderator if the SE staff see fit to appoint a fourth pro-tem.  However, the three who have already nominated are excellent choices as well.

I have been active on meta, especially as a silent voter, as active as possible on the main site, and also in both the site's main chat rooms; one named at my humble suggestion and the other my own room which is supposed to follow a somewhat lighter note.

I'm in the Eastern Time Zone (UTC-5 or UTC-4, depending on daylight savings).  As I am noticing, this puts me 3-5 hours off of all three of the other candidates, giving me the possibility of being on when they aren't.

**Note to those who don't recognize my username:  I was formerly anonymous2, and can be found under that name on the rest of the SE network.  I went *bang*  when I was the first to get the [Black Hole Aurora Hat](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yXcRFXtXO0BnBx6TGiJifYYzqvXe_kejgm__msSDVzE/edit#gid=0).**

Comment: Oh no, that pun was amazing ;)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[image]
[image: profile for tbm0115 on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I'd like to self-nominate as a back up. There are other users currently involved on this site that are much more knowledgeable on this topic.

The reason I'm willing to nominate myself is primarily because of my experience as a moderator on [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/). Given that I have an understanding of the IOT topic, I feel that I can appropriately and efficiently go through the moderator tasks.

Through my experience moderating on 3D Printing SE, I've setup a schedule to handle the workload, so I am fairly active on the site. My main goals on 3D Printing that I would continue to pursue (regardless of moderation status) is maintaining focus on working out of Beta status and maintaining Help Center/Tags.

Regardless, I am very excited to be part of this new community and I'm excited to have a resource for this topic.

Comment: Ah, that second one is your 3dprinting profile.  Thought it was your meta for a bit there and was wondering how on earth you had gotten a gold badge.  :)

Comment: Haha, REALLY active in Meta with 5 times the rep from the main site lol :)

Comment: Lol.  I just glanced quickly, and that was what was in the second spot on most of the other nominees, so I had to take a second look.  :)

Answer (score 4):

[image: profile for Mark Yisri at Internet of Things Stack Exchange, Q&A for users of everyday objects embedded with electronics to be sensed, monitored, and controlled remotely]

[image: profile for Mark Yisri at Ask Ubuntu, Q&A for Ubuntu users and developers]

[image: profile for Mark Yisri on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

my name is Mark Yisri and I would like to nominate myself for moderator.

## What might make me a bad moderator

I do not know a lot about IoT, as I wrote in [this post](http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/q/117/95).

## What might make me a good moderator

I can easily see when a question is not worded clear/is off-topic.

Comment: Best of luck for your nomination. Do you think you could still be a good candidate even though you're not all that knowledgeable about IoT? As long as you're still voting and participating, I think you could do the moderator tasks just fine, although some question/answer participation might be helpful (I understand it's hard, though - I'm not exactly an expert myself!)

Comment: @Aurora0001 I do believe I can handle these tasks. I can participate in some questions, but I might not know everything about home automation !

Comment: Best of luck :)