# How do we get the people who desperately want to use their new Christmas IoT stuff on the site?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Looks like we are not going public this year due to holidays.

> [**Please note** that with the anticipated slowdown in traffic during the end-of-year holidays, we will *not* be evaluating this site for public launch until after the new year. – Robert Cartaino♦](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site#comment234_133)

That begs the question how we get all those despaired souls to this site who get new IoT stuff on the holidays and just can't get it to work. Has anyone an idea besides word-of-mouth to get the word out? Ordinarily if we were public those questions about all the new toys that don't work and our great answers how they do get to work would be highly searchable on Google. Those days will be full of questions by people who try to figure out how their new stuff works. We just have to get them here.

Maybe there can be special Community Ads that advertises us over the holidays. I used my unparalleled(ly bad) paint skills to make a sketch.

[image: BestPaintSketchEverV2]

Do you guys have other ideas?

Comment: I think we need more experts to provide answers first - even more importantly than people firing up those questions about their new toys on christmas eve... but if you can make the Alexas under the christmas tree lure the people here that would be a great deal nonetheless.

Comment: @Ghanima I think the experts are generally not interested in giving their knowledge away for free here. Obviously there are great exceptions, but there really are not a lot of genuine experts. We need to rely a little on the end user side whilst the professional side matures to the point where people see the value in being open.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane the whole StackExchange network is based on the very idea to give your knowledge away for virtual internet points only ;) but your right, the site has to develop on both ends end users and experts.

Comment: Yes, we know that. Many organizations haven't learnt of the value of giving things away for free yet (hence all the stupid closed protocols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tweeted this image, and gained one user (with only 200 odd followers).