# Take Your Once-in-a-Lifetime "Beta"-Badge Opportunity in Private Beta!

Tags: discussion

[Since we won't be going public until 2017](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site#comment234_133), we as private beta users should make every effort to keep the fire burning until the site does get opened to the general public.

There is also a terrific badge to be earned by amping up your beta participation. [The beta badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/338924) Its requirements are very reasonably and only require you to do the following.

- **Vote 10 times**
- **Add 3 posts** **with a score greater than zero**
- **Visit the site on three different days**
- **Do this *before* we reach public beta**

> It will allow you to proudly pin a shiny silver beta badge to your <strike>chest</strike> profile that people will adore you for forever.

The one additional requirement the badge has is that we actually reach public beta. Luckily, everyone's own chasing of that badge with valuable questions, answers, votes and visits will help us get there. Hopefully, it will also broaden our pool people asking questions a bit.

Don't worry, our voting base doesn't bite. Only 7 from over a hundred questions have a negative score and no single answer is below zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Good news, everyone! The new Internet of Things Stack Exchange site is now open to the public.

Congrats and thank you to all ***nineteen*** honorees and everyone else who helped us get here. Let's keep getting more people involved, asking more great questions and providing great answers. On to site graduation we go :)

Answer (score 4):

We have not seen quite a lot [example questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94224/internet-of-things?phase=definition&tab=votes#tab-top) re-asked in Beta, so those how are registered and had some great example questions during Definition Phase do not hesitate to elaborate them and ask again.

They can be answered now, so it is an opportunity that should not be missed.